# Error while sending null value to stored procedure DateTime parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure parameter as:

```
@ScmDate DateTime = NULL
```

From C# when I pass the parameter as below, it gives error: **Error converting nvarchar to datetime.**

```
if (txtWaitedDate.Text != "")
    cmdTwMainEntry.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scmDate", Convert.ToDateTime(txtWaitedDate.Text));
```

Even though I have given default value of this parameter as NULL, but when the above C# condition is not fulfilled, it gives error.

**Edited:**

I get error only when I leave TextBox empty.

Comment: What is the value of txtWaitedDate.Text when it gives the error?

Comment: When I leave it blank, it gives error.

Comment: I think that txtWaitedDate.Text  has value '' (empty string) in this case and you need to replace it with Null.

Comment: I tried passing System.DBNull.value, but the same problem. If error is not shown than stored procedure is skipping inserting further column values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your date format is not what is expected by sql server, try to convert it with DateTime.TryParse and the right format provider for your SQL Server instance .

This error can happen for example when one is using mm/dd/yyyy format and the other is using dd/mm/yyyy.

**EDIT**

Changing the parameter type by hand should work anyway.
Try with this code, should work :

```
    SqlParameter parameter = cmdTwMainEntry.Parameters.Add("@scmDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
        // Set the value.
        parameter.Value = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtWaitedDate.Text)) ? Convert.ToDateTime(txtWaitedDate.Text) : System.DbNull.Value;
```

Comment: Please help me with the complete syntax.

Comment: The code you provided is for the condition when TextBox is not empty. I want the code for the condition when TextBox is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you send DbNull.Value when your textbox is empty.
That should do the trick, afaik.

Comment: ...but that shouldn't be necessary, if @ScmDate is NULL by default

Comment: @sq33G ...but in this case the error can be caused by this code Convert.ToDateTime(txtWaitedDate.Text)

Comment: If his test of txtWaitedDate.Text != "" is correctly returning false, that that line should never execute

Comment: @sq33G The stored procedure is not inserting further column values if a NULL date is encountered.

Comment: The stored procedure isn't getting that far, in your case; it's failing on the original call, because it can't make @ScmDate fit the value it's getting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are filling in wrong date (format). So this value couldn't be converted.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( DateTime.TryParse( txtWaitedDate.Text, out WaitedDate )
    Entry.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scmDate", WaitedDate );
else
    Entry.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scmDate", DBNull.Value );
```

Comment: Problem is with DBNull.Value as well. The stored procedure is not inserting further values if Date is not provided. It is not accepting any NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint before your SQL executes in C# and inspect your Parameters collection. It sounds like @ScmDate is sneaking in with a value like String.Empty.

Comment: I even tried: System.DBNull.Value, but still the same problem.

Comment: My point is that @ScmDate is getting into the Parameters collection, even when the code inside the condition doesn't execute.

Answer (score 0):

If you have **default value specified for the parameter** then there is no need to provide the value for that parameter while calling the stored procedure. For example if you have:

```
@ScmDate DateTime = NULL
```

Then simple solution is just to **ignore this parameter** when there is no value available for this parameter.